# 404 Not Found Error Without index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, error-handling

My Site - http://files.wpcoderx.com/ 
It is not working with index.php but if we add index.php after url it works fine.
 Example  - http://files.wpcoderx.com/index.php

Please tell me what can be issue there.

Comment: Perhaps you have index.html or at your server DirectoryIndex is not added index.php to be acceptable

Comment: Take a look at the documentation of the `DirectoryIndex` configuration command: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex

Comment: Everything is fine but still showing 404

Comment: /home/techinger/public_html/index.php is this the valid path ?

Comment: You did restart the http server after changing the configuration?

Comment: @arkascha yes i restarted apache via whm

Comment: @Svetlio No it is not valid path of files.wpcoderx.com. Path is -  
/home/techinger/public_html/files/index.php

Comment: You will have to post your configuration for us to help further...

Comment: @arkascha thanks for reply i will fix that now :)